# Displaying a map using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I am new to WPF, and relatively new to GUI coding, so bear with me if this seems obvious to some.

I am trying to display a randomly generated map using WPF/C#, in order to simulate the behaviour of a propagating RF signal.  Each map coordinate can have zero or more items within it - it could be buildings, vehicles, fauna or geographical data (none indicates flat grassy fields).  I would like to display this in a window, or on a page to the user.  But I don't know how.

My original thought was a canvas with a pre-defined method for drawing items.  But the map will be massive, and I only want to display a small portion of the map to the user at any one time.

So, what I want to know is, can I create a canvas, draw what I want onto it, and then display only a small portion of that to the user?  If not, or if that is not simple, is there a better way of doing it?  I don't necessarily want a specific answer either - a more generic solution would be better (i.e. tell me I need to use a "Blah" with a "Blah blah" would be better than writing out the whole code - I like to learn about these things as much as possible by doing, not copy and paste).

Thanks.

David

Answer (score 2):

Here some ideas:

You can try to paint your objects directly via the GraphicsContext. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx) you find an overview.

Also check out [CompositionTarget.Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx), it allows you also to render [per frame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838.aspx) (as far as possible).

If it is graphically intensive, perhaps it's also a good idea to look into the [XNA-framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791).